# Matrix Transformation for expanding gaps between eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, perturbation-theory

Hi I have a question towards how to expand the gaps between eigenvalues for one specific matrix.

1. Suppose that we have a matrix ${\bf A}$, and the eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_k\}$, suppose that the gaps between each consecutive eigenvalues are denoted by $\{\Delta_{1,2}, \Delta_{2,3},...\Delta_{k-1,k}\}$, and now I want to make some transformation on $\bf A$. Suppose we use matrix perturbation, and $\bf{B} = \bf{A} + \Delta$, and the minimum gaps for $\bf B$ is larger than some specific value say $\alpha$. So Does anyone have some ideal how to do this?
2. If I already have the transformation method, and I have matrix $\bf B$, I calculate all eigenvalues(eigen-pairs) of $\bf B$, can I recover matrix $\bf A$'s eigenvalues(eigen-pairs)?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ symmetric? (This sort of thing behaves somewhat badly in the nonsymmetric case.) Also, should $\Delta$ be small? How small if so?

Comment: I don't see any way to reliably do this without having some information about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$ a-priori

Comment: Hi, A and B are symmetric, and I do not have restrictions on $\bf \Delta$, thanks